# Is it possible to install mongodb without root privilages?

Tags: mongodb

How can I install mongodb on a Linux server without root privileges? is this possible? What would the steps be? Is there a way to configure mongo to not use /data/db?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may download the binaries from MongoDB website.

There are a lot of options for the command *mongod* to change the default behavior, one of these is:

> --dbpath arg           directory for datafiles

Based on comments:

But it is preferable to specify all configurations in a configuration file and just invoke mongod with:

> --config filename

Comment: by default it listens on port 27017. Note: you can specify all these (and much more) in a configuration file and use `--config filename`

Comment: Would simply changing the dbpath allow for non root user? Having an issue where Webstorm IDE can't start it's MongoDB explorer due to permissions issue. I am assuming this is why.

Comment: the "how" wasn't answered properly.